# Python textblob Translation API Error

Tags: python, translation, textblob

I have been using `textblob` in Python 2.7.10 on Windows for quite some time, and unexpectedly, it stopped working. Testing with two independent virtual machines as well as on OS X produces the same error.

Testing a simple snippet from the [docs](http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/quickstart.html#translation-and-language-detection):

```
    from textblob import TextBlob
    en_blob = TextBlob(u'Simple is better than complex.')
    print(en_blob.translate(to='es'))
```

produces an error:

> ```
> File "test.py", line 3, in <module> print(en_blob.translate(to='es'))
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 509, in translate
> from_lang=from_lang, to_lang=to))
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\translate.py", line 45, in translate
> raise NotTranslated('Translation API returned the input string unchanged.')
>
> textblob.exceptions.NotTranslated: Translation API returned the input string 
> unchanged.
> ```

How can I debug this error?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the docs, Textblob uses the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) for its translations.

Apparently, this (undocumented) API changed it's output format. I am able to do a succesfull request with this snippet:

```
import requests
url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t'
params = {
    "text": "Simple is better than complex", 
    "sl": "en", 
    "tl": "es", 
    "client": "p"
}
print(requests.get(url, params=params).content)

>> '"Simple es mejor que complejo"'
```

In the source code of textblob, code is indicating a `json` encoded approach, but apparently Google has decided here that simple is indeed better than complex.

This issue is already mentioned in https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/117.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with but with Language Detection not translation. Can you please help me in understanding how can I do the same with the above format.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Gijs, the Google Translate API changed.  This caused TextBlob's translation and language detection functionality to stop working.

I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/pull/118) to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `from_lang` parameter telling from which language you are translating:

```
en_blob = TextBlob(u'Simple is better than complex.')
print(en_blob.translate(from_lang='en', to='es'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Introducing the `from_lang` parameter does not solve the issue, in my experience.
I have fixed it calling Google's translation API from another front, not through textblob's.
https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans